# Can't figure out how to insert keys and values of nested JSON data into SQL rows with NiFi

Tags: sql, arrays, json, apache-nifi, jsonpath

I'm working on a personal project and very new (learning as I go) to JSON, NiFi, SQL, etc., so forgive any confusing language used here or a potentially really obvious solution. I can clarify as needed.

I need to take the JSON output from a website's API call and insert it into a table in my MariaDB local server that I've set up. The issue is that the JSON data is nested, and two of the key pieces of data that I need to insert are used as variable key objects rather than values, so I don't know how to extract it and put it in the database table. Essentially, I think I need to identify different pieces of the JSON expression and insert them as values, but I'm clueless how to do so.

I've played around with the EvaluateJSON, SplitJSON, and FlattenJSON processors in particular, but I can't make it work. All I can ever do is get the result of the whole expression, rather than each piece of it.

```
{"5381":{"wind_speed":4.0,"tm_st_snp":26.0,"tm_off_snp":74.0,"tm_def_snp":63.0,"temperature":58.0,"st_snp":8.0,"punts":4.0,"punt_yds":178.0,"punt_lng":55.0,"punt_in_20":1.0,"punt_avg":44.5,"humidity":47.0,"gp":1.0,"gms_active":1.0},

"1023":{"wind_speed":4.0,"tm_st_snp":26.0,"tm_off_snp":82.0,"tm_def_snp":56.0,"temperature":74.0,"off_snp":82.0,"humidity":66.0,"gs":1.0,"gp":1.0,"gms_active":1.0},

"5300":{"wind_speed":17.0,"tm_st_snp":27.0,"tm_off_snp":80.0,"tm_def_snp":64.0,"temperature":64.0,"st_snp":21.0,"pts_std":9.0,"pts_ppr":9.0,"pts_half_ppr":9.0,"idp_tkl_solo":4.0,"idp_tkl_loss":1.0,"idp_tkl":4.0,"idp_sack":1.0,"idp_qb_hit":2.0,"humidity":100.0,"gp":1.0,"gms_active":1.0,"def_snp":23.0},

"608":{"wind_speed":6.0,"tm_st_snp":20.0,"tm_off_snp":53.0,"tm_def_snp":79.0,"temperature":88.0,"st_snp":4.0,"pts_std":5.5,"pts_ppr":5.5,"pts_half_ppr":5.5,"idp_tkl_solo":4.0,"idp_tkl_loss":1.0,"idp_tkl_ast":1.0,"idp_tkl":5.0,"humidity":78.0,"gs":1.0,"gp":1.0,"gms_active":1.0,"def_snp":56.0},

"3396":{"wind_speed":6.0,"tm_st_snp":20.0,"tm_off_snp":60.0,"tm_def_snp":70.0,"temperature":63.0,"st_snp":19.0,"off_snp":13.0,"humidity":100.0,"gp":1.0,"gms_active":1.0}}
```

This is a snapshot of an output with a couple thousand lines. Each of the numeric keys that you see above (5381, 1023, 5300, etc) are player IDs for the following stats. I have a table set up with three columns: `Player ID`, `Stat ID`, and `Stat Value`. For example, I need that first snippet to be inserted into my table as such:

```
Player ID        Stat ID        Stat Value
5381             wind_speed     4.0
5381             tm_st_snp      26.0
5381             tm_off_snp     74.0
```

And so on, for each piece of data. But I don't know how to have NiFi select the right pieces of data to insert in the right columns.

Comment: check PutDatabaseRecord with json reader: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/index.html

Comment: @daggett I’ve looked at that, but I couldn’t figure out how to tell it which pieces of data to route where, to be honest. I’m confident this is doable, but don’t know what I don’t know in order to make it happen with any tool I’ve found so far.

Comment: @stevy thanks for the formatting updates

Comment: Is there variable number of stat keys for each player Id?

Comment: @daggett yep. And each week’s stats are different, so within each player ID it won’t be the same every time I run the workflow.

Comment: @daggett any other thoughts? Am I trying something that NiFi isn’t designed for?

Comment: Try jolt transformation to convert json to json close to required out data. I could show how to do it with script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it's possible to use jolt to transform your json into a format:

```groovy
[
  {"playerId":"5381", "statId":"wind_speed", "statValue": 0.123},
  {"playerId":"5381", "statId":"tm_st_snp", "statValue": 0.456},
  ...
]
```

then use PutDatabaseRecord with json reader.

---

Another approach is to use `ExecuteGroovyScript` processor.

Add new parameter to it with name `SQL.mydb` and link it to your DBCP controller service

[image]

And use the following script as `Script Body` parameter:

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return


//read flow file content and parse it
def body = ff.read().withReader("UTF-8"){reader-> 
    new JsonSlurper().parse(reader) 
}

def results = []
//use defined sql connection to create a batch
SQL.mydb.withTransaction{
    def cmd = 'insert into mytable(playerId, statId, statValue) values(?,?,?)'
    results = SQL.mydb.withBatch(100, cmd){statement->
        //run through all keys/subkeys in flow file body
        body.each{pid,keys->
            keys.each{k,v->
                statement.addBatch(pid,k,v)
            }
        }
    }
}

//write results as a new flow file content
ff.write("UTF-8"){writer-> 
    new JsonBuilder(results).writeTo(writer) 
}
//transfer to success
REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

Comment: Ahh yes, great. Can you help point me in the direction of how to transform it correctly using jolt? That looks exactly like what would be perfect, I just can't figure out how to get it there in playing around. Thanks so much for the groovy expression, that should work perfectly once I get the jolt part done

Comment: I've created groovy for your original json, so, you don't need jolt for it.

Comment: ohhhh gotcha. Do I need to edit anything to tell it which table to insert into, or is that supposed to be done in the DBCP controller? Or I just realized my table column names have underscores (Player_ID, etc).If I fix that to match, Will it find it automatically?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and patience on this, by the way. I really appreciate it.

Comment: There is an insert statement `insert into mytable(playerId, statId, statValue)` that you have to edit.

Comment: That was it!! Thank you so much!! As a note, I had to adjust my table field types to be VARCHAR, as it was throwing an illegal integer error when I had them set as integers. But it’s working now. @daggett you’re a champ!

Comment: One issue: it inserts correctly, but doesn’t ever stop. I let it run for a little while earlier and, on an expected maybe 200-300 lines, it inserted over 145 million, just with extreme repetition. My guess is that it means that it’s not actually passing to success and terminating for some reason. Any thoughts?

Comment: nope. Not throwing any errors, just never stopping insertion. I had to manually stop the processors to end the insertions

Comment: Should not be so. Try to set failure strategy - transfer to failure. Connect failure to logattribute but don't start it to see which flow files failed

Comment: honestly I’m not 100% sure what you mean. I set the ExecuteGroovyScript failure relationship to go to LogAttributes and ran all 3 processes (GetFile, ExecuteGroovyScript and LogAttributes), and it still put around ~15,000 lines in almost instantly (should be around 100). I’ve got the log output, but don’t see any issues, I don’t think?

Comment: There is a parameter `failure strategy` in executegroovyscript. Try to set it `transfer to failure`

Comment: Also try to put only 1 file into the input queue. Is it transferred to success or failure connection?

Comment: I set that to transfer to failure and it did move the attributes to the log as expected. I also cut down the source to a single JSON object '{"5381":{"wind_speed":4.0}}' and it logged it into failure many times in about 5 seconds, so just doesn't seem to be terminating correctly.

Comment: As a note, I also put a return in at the end of the script, but that didn’t help either. Wasn’t sure if it was needed, but seemed worth a try.

Comment: stop all. just put one simple file in the input folder. start and stop the GetFile. expecting to have one file in the input queue of script. then start and stop script. check if file was processed (inserted into db), check if file transferred to success or failure connection.

Comment: Ohhhh. Looks like GetFile was actually causing the issue. Keep Source File was set to True, meaning it grabbed the file in perpetuity. Yikes. My fault. I'm planning to use InvokeHTTP anyway, so that means the script should be good to go. I know eventually I'll need to add something into that Groovy script that transfers 2 pieces of the URL used in InvokeHTTP to the database; can you point me to any resources where I can learn Groovy better to fix that as well?